# Trying to get #include <gmpxx.h> to run in my program

Tags: include, gnu, gmp, bignum

In my code I'm getting a fatal error of :

> fatal error: gmpxx.h: No such file or directory|

I'm trying to use the The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library, but I'm having trouble trying to get the library downloaded an working in the right place.

I download the file `gmp=6.1.0.tar.lz` but I have no idea how to open it, use it, or even where it needs to be placed.

I'm using Codeblocks, and a Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install some basic GNU utilities via [MinGW](http://sf.net/p/mingw). We need `tar`. Then, download a [stable lzip release](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lzip/). Choose **tarball** not **lzip** archive, because we want to build lzip. Now, open your MSYS shell, go to directory made after extracting lzip tarball (this directory should be available as `/c/<PATH ON C DRIVE WITH BACKSLASHES REPLACED WITH SLASHES>`) and run:

```
./configure --prefix=/
make
make install
```

Then go up (`cd ..`) and run:

```
tar xvf gmp-6.1.0.tar.lz
```

It should extract this file. Now, build GMP by going to directory `gmp-6.1.0` and running:

```
PATH="/c/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW:$PATH" ./configure --prefix='/c/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW'
```

on 32-bit system, or:

```
PATH="/c/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW:$PATH" ./configure --prefix='/c/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW' --enable-cxx
```

on 64-bit. Run these commands:

```
make
make install
```

You should have GMP installed.

Comment: I did the ./configure --prefix=/ and it worked, however when I did , make , I get this:    cc -W -02 -c -o carg_parser.o carg_parser.c   make: cc: Command not found   make: *** [carg_parser.o] Error 127

Comment: Wait, what should I be  putting something after the --prefix=/

Comment: Never mind! Got it! Thanks you so much for you help!